# Visual Studio 2013 with mdf and SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-express

I have a WEP API service project written by another developer with a test database in a `.MDF` file. Initially the database was working great. Then I tried to run the service project as a local IIS instance (he was running it only through VS) and all hell broke loose. The error I'm receiving is this:

> cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 662

Now, I do have Visual Studio 10 and 12 installed, but I'm running this through 13, Ultimate edition. The thing that has me scratching my head is I also do have SQL Server Dev 2012 installed. Trying to run the project again inside of VS instead of IIS has no effect as well.

Any thoughts and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your database file is version **706** which corresponds to SQL Server **2012**, while your server you're trying to use to attach this file to is version **662** (SQL Server **2008 R2**). So either you're trying to use a newer version of the database file with an older server (which isn't supported), or you're attaching the `.mdf` file to a wrong instance that is an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: That much I gathered, but I have SQL Server 2012 already installed.  I'm using it on other projects.  Why is it reverting to an older version?

Comment: It's not *reverting* - you're trying to attach to an older version.... check your connection strings - what instance does it refer to? Check that instance's version with `SELECT @@Version` - I bet you have an older 2008 R2 instance somewhere, and you're connecting to that one.....

Comment: Write now I'm having trouble connecting to it through Visual Studio as well, though I could initially. Here's the connection string: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|Data Directory|XXXXX.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=True

Comment: The **simplest** solution would be to put the database where it belongs: **on the server**. Create it **on the server**, and connect to it using nothing but the **logical database name** - stop fiddling around with free-floating files, that's just a recipe for disaster and endless grief.......

Comment: Agreed but can't solve that issue today. Thought about flat out importing the mdf into a real Sql Server instance locally but was trying to figure out what on Earth I did to break the mdf.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install SQL Server Express 2012. I think you are running SQL Server Express 2008.

Sql7 , 515

Sql2000 , 539

Sql2005sp1 , 611

Sql2005sp2 , 612

Sql2008sp1(dev10sp1) , 655

Sql2008sp2 ,

Sql2008sp3 ,

Sql2008r2 , 661

Sql2012(RC0) , 705  , Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RC0 - 11.0.1750.32

Sql2012(RC1/RTM) , 706 , Microsoft SQL Server 2012 RC0 - 11.0.1913.38

Comment: The other thing was why was it working before I tried to run it through IIS?

Comment: If you have 2008 instaled .remove it.and also if you going to try somthing,always make a backup of the importand files.if somthing goed wrong you can always fall back or you're testing on a copy and there will be no risk to begin with.